# Why won't Make merge pattern rule prerequisites, and how do I make it do this?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When I run this Makefile:

```
foo.x:
.PHONY: a b
%.x: a
%.x: b
    $(error [$^])
```

I see:

```
Makefile:5: *** [b].  Stop.
```

Why do I not see `[a b]` instead of `[b]`? How do I make Make include both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, like that.  The make manual says that pattern rules without a recipe [cancel the pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).

You can write the pattern rule with all prerequisites in the same rule:

```
%.x: a b
        $(error [$^])
```

Or you can define the extra prerequisite on the non-pattern target:

```
foo.x: a
%.x: b
        $(error [$^])
```